# DetailViewController in SplitViewController Displaying in Wrong Position

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using a storyboard and auto-layout for an iOS 7 project. I have a SplitViewController with the master view controller and detail view controller relationships set. The master view controller is correctly displaying aligned left, but the detail view is displaying centered, behind the master view, not aligned left like it should be: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12009928/2014-03-19%2021.50.43.png

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the view on the Detail Controller, is it properly aligned to the edge of the view controller. Trying giving background colour (other than white) for your Detail View Controller and View to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: That was part of the problem. The other part was that my UISplitViewController was actually declared as an ordinary UIViewController with a UISplitViewController as a member of it. I properly set it to be a UISplitViewController and removed the extraneous members. Thanks for the help!